# Android: how to notify Activity when Button in Fragment was clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, events, button, android-activity

I have a fragment that handle a button, i want my Activity to be notified when this button is clicked, Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :

1.Create one interface

2.Implement that in your activity

3.Pass its object to your fragment

4.And onclick of that button call Interface's method using that object

Comment: Ok thank you it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Observer Pattern to make such a handler, more info [Observer Design Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html)